# How to define a View in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, view

i´m trying to create a View using EF with CodeFirst.
I´ve already managed to creat one using the modelbuilder

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<XXXDbo>(c =>
    {
        c.HasNoKey();
        c.ToView("V_XXX");
    });
```

But to actually create the View i had to write a fitting SQL Statement for my migration file.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.\"V_XXX\" + ..." ");
```

Is there a way to automaticly create the SQL Statement for the migrationBuilder? Right now i have to manually paste the statement everytime i create a new migration.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an example:

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<ProductionRatingAverage>()
.ToView(nameof(ProductionRatingAverages))
.HasKey(t => t.Id);
```

You can check this article for details: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/how-to-add-a-view-to-an-entity-framework-core-dbcontext